# Excel coloring cells from a named range using the ranges colors

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automatically color the cell in a column of values, based upon a named range of statuses which have the relevant color that the cell needs to pick up. For example:

---

Worksheet 1

Column A    |  Column B     |    Column C
A Name A     |     Dept AAA    |       Status 1
A Name B     |     Dept AAA     |     Status 2
A Name C    |      Dept BBB     |     Status 1
A Name D    |      Dept CCC      |    Status 3
A Name E     |     Dept BBB      |    Status 2

---

In a separate worksheet which has the named range Statuses
Worksheet 2
Column A
Status 1          (Cell colored a shade of green)
Status 2          (Cell colored a shade of blue)
Status 3          (Cell colored a shade of pink)

So what I want is all the Status 1's in column C of Worksheet 1 to be colored the shade of green, the Status 2's to be the shade of blue and the status 3 to be pink.
There are around 30 statuses currently colored one of four colors. These colors may change in the future and there may be additional ones therefore it should automatically pick up these colors.

Any help gratefully received

Comment: @pnuts My route exactly :) , but your link doesn't seem to show the tutorial?

Comment: Yeah conditional formatting is the way to go.

Comment: With conditional formatting I would have to put in conditions for all 30 statuses and then amend them every time there was a change in color or new statuses were added (which is likely). If there was a way to do this via programming, changes to the conditional formatting wouldn't have to be done on each change. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @rumsoft I think you are wrong. You can apply the conditional format in one cell to as many cells as you want. People here can show you how to do that. So once you have your conditional format set up you can apply it to as many cells as you want and you can change it fairly easily when you need to. You would have to update your VBA code with new color conditions if you went that route as well. So using conditional formatting should work just as well or better.

Comment: @pnuts No I didn't scroll down... You didn't ask me to.. :-P I see it now lol..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Stephan1010 that conditional formatting would be the best route. It should be a little more manageable too because you only have 4 colors, which means 4 conditions with an OR statement containing all of the applicable statuses. You wouldn't have to amend all 30 if a color/status were to change...

That being said, while it will **severely impact the performance of your workbook**, it ***could*** be done in vba via the worksheet events. The first piece of code would capture any change to Column C in worksheet 1 and update the background color (other changes can be done as well of course)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

minCol = Target.Cells(1, 1).Column
maxcol = minCol + (Target.Columns.Count - 1)
If minCol > 3 Or maxcol < 3 Then
Else
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Column = 3 Then
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, 
                              Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Statuses"), 0))     
            Then
                x = Application.Match(_
                        cell,Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Statuses"), 0)
               cell.Interior.Color = Worksheets("Sheet1")._
                                      Range("Statuses").Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End If
End Sub
```

Then you'd need to capture any change to your Statuses Range in Worksheet 1 and update *every applicable value* in worksheet 2. This would be even more involved, and if this step is truely necessary, then you should be able to get it started and essentially implement the reverse logic of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For Coloring The Excel Cell Range:

worksheet.Cells["A2:AZ"].interior.color= System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

For Removing Color from Excel Cell Range:

xlWorkSheet1.Range["A2:AZ"].Interior.ColorIndex = 0;